# One Column modification using trigger if other coulmn is blank

Tags: plsql

In my system we are generating alarm alias based on device status so it's working for some data but not for all objects so I have find out one solution like if that device don't have any value in alarm alias column then I will try to update last modified date for that objects and next run it will generate alarm alias.
So now I want to write a trigger for updating last modified date column if alarms alias filled is blank.
Kindly suggest or let meknow how it can be implemented in plsql..

Comment: Will make it much simpler to help, if you post your table structure or DDL statement

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but if you are working with a single table, try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema.activity_log_t1
   BEFORE INSERT or update
   ON myschema.activity_log
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       activity_log_t1
   PURPOSE:    Set default field values in activity_log table
   Modified:   2016.02.09 - BFL Created
******************************************************************************/
BEGIN
   IF :new.alarm_alias IS NULL
   THEN
      :new.modified_date   := SYSDATE;
   END IF;
END activity_log_t1;
/
```